# Why I have access to an authorized useron a local windows account and not when I am logged in a domain one?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

I can authorize a user for a specific Active Directory and get the user's groups when I execute the code as a local wndows account.
However I get acces denied, when I am logged in a specific domain account

What should I add to my api ? Maybe windows user credentials ? And where to add them ?

```
ADContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADSettings.Domain, ADSettings.User, ADSettings.Password);

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user.Username);

var groups = user.GetGroups(); //this one fails.
```

StackTrace

at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Utils.GetDSHandle(String domainControllerName, String domainName, IntPtr authIdentity, LoadLibrarySafeHandle libHandle)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.GetDSHandle()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.GetDomainControllerInfo()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.get_SiteName()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroupsHelper()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroups()

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually doing. What do you mean by "I can authorize a user for a specific Active Directory"? Can you show us the code that is failing?

Comment: @GabrielLuci The code runs in my laptop, but when I am in university logged in Windows as user of the university, I get access denied.

I added the code.

Comment: Can you show all the details of the exception? The part before the stack trace.

Comment: i used user.GetAuthorizedGroups() and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean [`GetAuthorizationGroups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups). Keep in mind that will not give you distribution lists, only security groups.